# Pages rendering as source code in Chrome

Tags: bug, status-norepro

I tried repeatedly to answer a question today and 3 times in a row got the source code for the CAPTCHA page redirection instead of actually being redirected there. Today I hit similar issues on a number of pages on the StackExchange network. It seems that for some reason your web server (or the content distribution network's server) is inserting a 0 and some blank lines before the HTTP headers, and Chrome then renders source code instead of the web page. Example below:

[image]

Comment: is your version browser [officially supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)?

Comment: This looks more like a network / CDN problem. When you read this comment give us an update, does the problem persist? If it does, is everything else on the network working all right for you? Problems with other browsers? Had some similar issues myself, it was the CDN and everything worked fine after a couple of days.

Comment: Has this reoccurred for you?

Comment: I haven't seen the problem re-occur since posting the question. Will update if I see it Jarod, thanks.